# Problema al añadir una nueva vista dinámica en android Studio(método .addView())

Tags: android-studio

tengo un problema con el método addView ya que cada vez que intento añadir una vista para cargarla el programa falla y se sale. El caso es que si quito ese método del código el programa me funciona perfectamente. Este es mi código del mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentoSeleccionarDificultad.ResponderDificultad,
View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

    private int personaje = 0;
    private int dificultad = 0;
    Button tiledBoton;
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    LinearLayout main;
    public static final int PRINCIPIANTE = 8;
    public static final int AMATEUR = 12;
    public static final int AVANZADO = 16;
    //MotorJuego motorJuego;
    boolean jugando = false;
    //TypedArray arrayImagenes;
    int encontradas = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
        //rellenaBotones(PRINCIPIANTE);

    }
/*
    /**
     * Genera la matriz de botones inicial.
     *
     * @param botones Número de botones de acuerdo al nivel de dificultad.
     */
    private void rellenaBotones(int botones) {
        tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        tableLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
        tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        tableLayout.setWeightSum(botones);

        for (int i = 0; i < botones; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

            for (int j = 0; j < botones; j++) {
                tiledBoton = new Button(this);
                tiledBoton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tiledBoton.setId(View.generateViewId());
                tiledBoton.setText(i + "," + j);
                tiledBoton.setTextSize(0);
                tiledBoton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
                tiledBoton.setOnLongClickListener((View.OnLongClickListener) this);
                tr.addView(tiledBoton);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tr);
        }
        //EL PROBLEMA ESTÁ EN EL EL LINEAR LAYOUT MAIN
        main.removeAllViews();
        main.addView(tableLayout);

        if (!jugando) deshabilitaTablero(tableLayout);
    }
```

Este es mi código del XML de la vista que quiero añadir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1sp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.hipotenochas.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

No entiendo el problema con este método ya que con otros proyectos también me ha dado fallos. Igual es porque hay extender otro tipo de actividad o algo o hacer algún tipo de implementación. Si es así me gustaría una aclaración.

Comment: Comenta la linea y comparte el error que te lanza el editor por favor

Comment: main.addView(tableLayout); esa es la línea. No me sale un error como tal solamente me echa de la aplicación.

Comment: El problema, (creo, por lo que puedo ver) es que estas creando un `LinearLayout` inexistente en tu `MainActivity` y este al crearlo-lo busca pero no lo encuentra. Ahora, para controlar esto, observa en tu `LogCat` al momento de cuando se cierra tu app. Y muéstranos el error del mismo

Comment: Estos son los errores del logCat                                                                 
 2021-11-05 18:30:26.762 885-885/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.fp.fod"
2021-11-05 18:30:26.762 885-885/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.fp.sideCap".